# How Hashmap internally manages with buckets when a bucket reach its capacity

Tags: java

In an interview it was asked that what happens when a hashmap buckets overflows, will it store new entries to the nearest bucket or give any exception.

Comment: What do you mean by _buckets overflow_? How are buckets implemented?

Comment: It might be of help if you could more exactly quote the question that was asked in your interview.

Comment: my query is as one bucket can store more then one key-value pair and the hashmap looks at the hash code of the key every time to find the respective bucket..so there would be some maximum size/limit of bucket after that it may overflow ?

Answer (score 1):

They don't overflow ... assuming that you are referring to `java.util.HashMap` or `java.util.Hashtable`.  In both of these classes, each bucket is effectively a pointer (a reference) to a *chain* of hash entries.

> Is there some maximum size/limit of bucket after that it may overflow ?

No, there isn't.  Hash chains can be as long as they need to be ... assuming you have a big enough heap.

Comment: Well, you can't have more buckets than memory, can you? :D

Comment: @prakash - that's what I said.

Comment: @Mackiavelli - The question is not about the number of buckets.  (That is bounded by Integer.MAX_VALUE.).  The question is about whether the buckets overflow.